# Php Fetch Results into the table

Tags: php, html, html-table

Below are my codes, However, I didn't get a table as I expect. Rather than the first row only seeming to be ok, Other Rows are not coming in the table. Please refer to the photo.

```php
    $Sql = "SELECT Registration_Number,Name FROM vta";
    
    $Result = $conn->Query($Sql);
    
    
    if ($Result -> num_rows> 0) {    
        echo "<table border=2> 
            <tr><th>Registration_Number</th>
            <th>Name</th></tr>";
    
        while ($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // $Rm=$Row['Registration_Number'];
            // $Nm = $Row['Name'];
    
            echo "<tr><td>$Row[Registration_Number]</td><td>$Row[Name]</td></tr></table>";
        }
    }
    
    $conn->Close();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i80fm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the closing `</table>` outside the loop.

```php
$Sql = "SELECT Registration_Number,Name FROM vta";

$Result = $conn->Query($Sql);


if($Result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table border=2> 
        <tr><th>Registration_Number</th>
        <th>Name</th></tr>";

    while ($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>$Row['Registration_Number']</td><td>$Row['Name']</td></tr>";
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

$conn->Close();
```

Comment: Then please mark my answer as accepted :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work